# "ERROR: UndefVarError: `MyModule` not defined" when using a simple custom module in julia

Tags: module, julia

I recently installed julia and so far it has been working fine.
I have version 1.9.2 of julia.
I have Windows 11 installed.
I am using VS Code as a text editor.
I wanted to create a custom module, a very simple one, with just a function inside.
I called the module MyModule and saved it inside the file "MyModule.jl"
[Here is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5mPf.png)
Then I opened the terminal, browsed to the path where "MyModule.jl" is contained and opened REPL.
If I type "using .MyModule", I get the error: "ERROR: UndefVarError: `MyModule` not defined"
[Here is a screenshot of my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BotSp.png)
Can someone explain why this is happening? What am I missing?

I tried removing the extension .jl in the module file, nothing changes.
I tried to insert the statement "using .MyModule" inside another .jl file and than run that file, but it does not work either.
I tried to close everything and than repeat the procedure, but i get the same results.
I was expecting to be able to use the module without getting errors.

Comment: You need to include the file first with `include("MyModule.jl")`.

Comment: I would reccomend Pkg.jl's generate(). ("] generate MyModule"). Then populating it with your functionalities, etc. See https://pkgdocs.julialang.org/v1/creating-packages/

Comment: basically, unlike Python, you can't "just" import modules from files, that's very fragile anyway, not recommended even in Python